# Removing actionListeners

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm building some GUI in Java (J2ME) and have doubts what is the best practice to avoid resource/memory leaks pertaining to actionListeners.

Let's say I have a class object that has a member variable that adds an actionListener. Do I need to remove this actionListener explicitly before the object goes out of scope? By not removing the actionListener, will I create a memory/resource leak, when the MyPanel class object goes out of scope?

```
public class MyPanel implements ActionListener
{

    private LabelButton _button;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        _button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    ... 
}
```

Comment: If your app. is crashing based on the extra memory used by a few (or a few dozen) buttons and their listeners, it has bigger problems than use of those buttons.

Comment: Who said anything about the app is crashing?

Comment: *"Who said anything about the app is crashing?"* You mentioned  *'memory leaks'* (which would ultimately cause `OutOfMemoryError`).

Comment: A small memory leak will never crash any app as long as there are resources/memory left. Code should never leak a single byte though.

Answer (score 3):

With `getListeners` / `getActionListeners` you can get all Listeners registered at a specified element, and with `removeActionListener` you can remove a Listener from an element

Example:

```
for(ActionListener act : buttonToBeFreedFromListeners.getActionListeners()) {
    buttonToBeFreedFromListeners.removeActionListener(act);
}
```

Just a note: As long as you do not save references to the Listeners that are registered at your elements, the GarbageCollector will pick up the Listeners when he picks up the elements, as they have the only reference to it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to remove explicitly, java takes care in most cases, what I would do is not worry about it now, if memory is leaking then you can use specialized software like [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)

Comment: This is bad advice.  Java will not collect the `MyPanel` object while there is a reference to it from the list of action listeners in the button.  You really shouldn't have the attitude of writing buggy code and only fixing it later on when the user notices it hogging memory...

Comment: I guess you're right, this code doesn't respect separation of duties code style.