# How to delete/disable an actionListener?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I added several `ActionListener` to my `commandButton`. How to proceed to have only one active?
I used:

```
MethodExpression addLastmemo = _ef.createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{dashboardBean.getLastMemo}", Void.class, new Class[]{ActionEvent.class});
button.addActionListener(new MethodExpressionActionListener(addLastmemo));
```

Is there a way to delete/disable an `actionListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
button.removeActionListener(new MethodExpressionActionListener(addLastmemo));
```

Comment: Did you try button.getActionListeners and iterate over them and apply button.removeActionListener on each one of them?

Comment: yes it's done, i use that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731328/removing-actionlisteners. Thanks for your help.